# Reference object inside same variable

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript file which is containing styles in an object for a React app:

```
const styles = {
  fonts: {
    Georgia: 'Georgia, \'Times New Roman\', Times, serif',
  },
  App: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: this.fonts.Georgia,
  },
};

module.exports = styles;
```

`fontFamily: this.fonts.Georgia` would reference `App: { fonts: '' }` object, but what I want to do is to access the already defined `fonts` object inside `styles`. How can I do that?

What works is:

```
const fonts = {
  Georgia: 'Georgia, \'Times New Roman\', Times, serif',
};

const styles = {
  App: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: fonts.Georgia,
  },
};

module.exports = styles;
```

This is works in this case, but the upper solution would be much nicer.

Comment: assign it to a variable?

Comment: This is impossible if you absolutely want to do this inside a object expression using only **`this`**.

Comment: @AndrewL. Unfortunately `styles.fonts.Georgia` not worked.

Comment: The proposed duplicate is wrong. This is a different question with a different answer.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha that seemed right to me

Comment: @DanielA.White The proposed duplicate was about `this` not being available on a variable (and only inside a function), this is about `this` being too deep in the tree, and thus not being able to access properties higher up the tree with it.

Comment: @AndrewL. The idea is that it should be `styles.App.fontFamily`.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Ahh, gotcha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply speaking, you can't. JavaScript objects have no notion of parentage.

```
const App = {
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontFamily: this.fonts.Georgia, // ???
}
```

What does `this` means in that context?

Moreover

```
const styles = {
  fonts: 'Georgia, \'Times New Roman\', Times, serif',
  App
};
```

This is the same object as the first one you've posted.

Your only choice is to split the two objects as you have. To hide this detail away from outside of the module, you can do the following:

```
module.exports = {fonts, styles};
```

That will make it so that both the fonts and the styles are available to the outside. You can mix and match to get the exact object you want, but the actual structure is irrelevant for the question.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, thank you for the clarification.  Later on there will be more fonts and I wanted to store the entire stylesheet under the same variable, but looks like this is not possible if I want to reference things inside the same parent variable.

Comment: You could hold a reference to `styles` inside of `App` (you'll still need to define them separately), and once you do that, you will be able to access it with something like `this.styles`, of course, it allows for circular references (`this.styles.App.styles.App.styles....`), so be careful when recursively iterating.

Answer (score 1):

An approach that works is using a getter to retrieve the `fonts` property dynamically.

```js
const styles = {
  fonts: {
    Georgia: 'Georgia, \'Times New Roman\', Times, serif',
  },
  App: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    get fontFamily () { return styles.fonts.Georgia },
  },
};

console.log(styles);
```

Note that this has some drawbacks:

- The `App.fontFamily` property will always mirror `fonts` if it changes dynamically. This may or may not be the desired behavior.
- Without a setter, `App.fontFamily` can only be get, not set.
- Some serializers may not process objects with non-value properties as one would expect. I guess this is true for some other libraries, too.

Comment: Is there any performance hit using `get` inside objects? If I start to treat inline styles in React like Sass or Stylus stylesheets, I will cross-reference in an object a lot with `get`.

Comment: Yes, but I suspect the impact should be negligible, even with a lot of objects. For me, with this code, maintainability would be the biggest concern (because of the reasons above).